# jQuery strange issue with data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

My code looks like that

```
$(document).on("click", ".search-user", function (e) {
    var userID = $(this).data('id').toString();
     ...
```

Getting error message in firebug

```
TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined
```

The strange thing is, when I alert userID right after initialization line, I got result.

Comment: What do you mean by *"right after initialization line"*..? what result did you get..?

Comment: Provide sample which replicates your issue

Comment: you mention `userId` but code is expecting `id` ... which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/et7mm2ov/

Basically, remove the `.toString()`

```js
$(document).on("click", ".search-user", function(e) {
  var userId = $(this).data('id');

  alert(userId);
});
```

```html
<input type='button' value='test' class='search-user' data-id='hello' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this to takes the data value

```
$(document).on("click", ".search-user", function (e) {
    var userID = $(this).attr('data-id').toString();
     ...
```

Comment: bad suggestion, if anything was set using `data()` it won't be changed in the attribute, only the object properties

Comment: I thought he wanted to get something like this.
<input data-id="2">